# Why does one and only one parabola pass through the three points given by a function?

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

I am doing integration by Simpson's method and in the question it says that one and only one parabola is associated with the three points  given by the function. Can someone please show me how this is so?

[image]

Comment: Parabola is defined by 3 parameters, $a, b, c$. 3 points give you 3 equations thus the set of equations either has exactly one solution or none at all!

Comment: I think you mean one and only one parabola **with vertical axis**.

Comment: Great well written answer!As for why the parabola is unique... It's because a parabola has a slope that changes in relation to x rather than being constant. Therefore, the first space (x1 to x2) gives a slope that is somewhere within [x1,x2].The third point than gives another slope somewhere between [x2,x3].These two slopes in combination with their locations gives the gradual change in slope.This gradual change in slope gives a second degree differential equation.Then, solving this differential equation requires 2 initial values (any 2 known points).We have those, so now we prove it's unique!

Answer (score 2):

If the parabola $y = a + bx + cx^2$ passes through the points $(x_0, y_0)$, $(x_1, y_1)$, and $(x_2, y_2)$, with $x_0 < x_1 < x_2$, then
$$
a(1,1,1) + b(x_0, x_1, x_2) + c(x_0^2, x_1^2, x_2^2) = (y_1, y_2, y_3).
$$
Now, **$\boldsymbol{(1,1,1), (x_0, x_1, x_2),}$ and $\boldsymbol{(x_0^2, x_1^2, x_2^2)}$ are linearly independent,**$^{1}$
So there is only one way to write any vector as a linear combination of them.
In particular, $a, b,$ and $c$ are determined.

---

$^{1}$
To prove this, you can calculate the determinant:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
x_0 & x_1 & x_2 \\
x_0^2 & x_1^2 & x_2^2
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
It should come out to
$$
(x_2 - x_1)(x_3 - x_1)(x_3 - x_2),
$$
which is nonzero because $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$.

Comment: Do we need to add the requirement that the points must not be on the same level? Otherwise, $y_1 = y_2= y_3$.

Comment: @Mick Such a requirement is not needed, as long as we are okay with degenerate parabolas. In particular if $y_1 = y_2 = y_3$, the argument in this answer is fine, except we'll get $b = c = 0$. What we have proven is that there is a unique quadratic OR linear OR constant function going through the three points.

Comment: I have no question about your proof. The question itself requires there is one and one parabola... Of course, a straight line can be considered also as  a parabola, a degenerated one.

Comment: @Mick Sure. What I was trying to say is, let's take "parabola" to include the degenerate cases.

Answer (score 0):

We know that two parabolas can have a maximum of 4 intersection points so if this is true and we consider any three particular points. There could be 2 parabolas passing through 3 points.