# How do I complete the proof that any three points (with unique x-values) can be fitted with a parabola, using linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, factoring

I have found this relevant question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933499/why-does-one-and-only-one-parabola-pass-through-the-three-points-given-by-a-func), which gives the result, but doesn't show how to get to the neatly factored answer, which completes the proof.

A parabola goes through the points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$ such that $x_1 \neq x_2 \neq x_3 $. To show that there is exactly one second degree polynomial solution, we can plug the points into the generic form $y = ax^2+bx+c$ and put those in matrix equation form of *A**x** = **b***, where
$$
    A =\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\
    x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\
    x_3^2 & x_3 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

If we can show that $det(A) \neq 0$, this is equivalent to showing that there's exactly one solution to this system.

Using column expansion, $$det(A) = (x_2^2 \cdot x_3 - x_2 \cdot x_3^2) - (x_1^2 \cdot x_3 - x_1 \cdot x_3^2) + (x_1^2 \cdot x_2 - x_1 \cdot x_2^2)$$

This can be factored to $$(x_2 \cdot x_3)(x_2 - x_3) - (x_1 \cdot x_3)(x_1-x_3)+(x_1 \cdot x_2)(x_1 - x_2)$$

I can continue with $$x_3[x_2(x_2-x_3)-x_1(x_1-x_3)] + x_1[x_2(x_1-x_2)]$$

How do you continue factoring to get to the form $$(x_1 - x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_3)$$?

Comment: This is the Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: It is cleaner if you subtracted the second and third row from the first, then use column expansion.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, as they are equal.

Comment: @ElliotG I'm asking how to continue factoring the expression stepwise to arrive at the final cleaner form, which clearly shows that the determinant cannot be zero.

Comment: @player3236 Great suggestion, it simplifies beautifully. That said, do you know how to keep stepwise factoring the expression above to arrive at the simplified form?

Comment: I guess $$\begin{align}&\quad\  x_3(x_2(x_2-x_3)-x_1(x_1-x_3))+x_1x_2(x_1-x_2) \\&= x_3(x_2^2-x_1^2 - x_2x_3+x_1x_3)+x_1x_2(x_1-x_2) \\&= (x_1-x_2)(x_1x_2+x_3(x_3-x_2-x_1))\\&=(x_1-x_2)(x_1x_2-x_1x_3-x_2x_3+x_3^2))\\&=(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_3)\end{align}$$

Comment: As stated in the title, the result is false.  There will be no parabolas fitting all three points if the points are collinear.  (The degree of the fitting polynomial will have degree $\lt 2$ in that case.)

Comment: @RobertShore I'm okay with degenerate parabolas, and it's okay if you're not.